# How to get the pressed keys in Swift

Tags: macos, keyboard, swift, sprite-kit, keyboard-events

I am trying to learn the Swift language, and I followed a lot of tutorials on Youtube. Since most of them are for iOS, I wanted to make the OSX version of this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PrVHrs10to (SideScroller game)

I followed it carefully but I am stuck at about 22 minutes of the video when I have to update the player position. My first problem was to get the pressed keys. I come from C# language, so I wanted to find something like

```
If(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    man.Position.x += 5 //player position
```

but this doesn't exist, so I figured out this:

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent!)
{
    updateManPosition(theEvent)
}
func updateManPosition(theEvent:NSEvent)
{
    if theEvent.keyCode == 123
    {
        man.position.x -= 2
    }
    else if theEvent.keyCode == 124
    {
        man.position.x += 2
    }
    else if theEvent.keyCode == 126
    {
        println("jump")
    }
}
```

I found the corresponding value(123/124/126) by using `println(theEvent.keyCode)` but it's not very useful if I have to recognize a lot of keys.
Anyway, it works for this game, the position of the player changes. But I have another probem which is that the function `keyDown` doesn't seem to be called at each update (so 60 times per seconds) which prevent the player to move smoothly.

SO, here is my question: **How can I have *keyDown* called at each update, and does anybody have a cleaner way to get the pressed Keys ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found how to update, so I post it here 'cause it might help others. The idea is to use a boolean:

```
var manIsMoving:Bool = false

override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) // A key is pressed
{
    if theEvent.keyCode == 123
    {
        direction = "left" //get the pressed key
    }
    else if theEvent.keyCode == 124
    {
        direction = "right" //get the pressed key
    }
    else if theEvent.keyCode == 126
    {
        println("jump")
    }
    manIsMoving = true //setting the boolean to true
}

override func keyUp(theEvent: NSEvent!)
{
    manIsMoving = false 
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{
    if manIsMoving
    {
        updateManPosition(direction)
    }
    else
    {
        cancelMovement()
    }
}
```

It may help others.
But getting the pressed key's characters is still unclear...

Answer (score 2):

In combination with the above method I have created a method to change a key to a character:

```
private func returnChar(theEvent: NSEvent) -> Character?{
    let s: String = theEvent.characters!
    for char in s{
        return char
    }
    return nil
}
```

This will return a character (from the key that was pressed).
Then you can do something like this:

```
override func keyUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let s: String = String(self.returnChar(theEvent)!)
    switch(s){
    case "w":
        println("w")
        break
    case "s":
        println("s")
        break
    case "d":
        println("d")
        break
    case "a":
        println("a")
        break


    default:
        println("default")
    }
}
```

You could combine this method and the method from above to create something like a key listener.

Comment: comparing characters is a bad idea for games due to different keyboard locales a key like "/" may require shift or other modifiers on some but not all locales