# Keys pressed - Swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, sprite-kit

I am trying to run some code when the user presses the space bar, does anyone know how to do this? Key codes would be helpful. I am programming in Swift an using SpriteKit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the pressed keys in Swift and SpriteKit at every Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058702/how-to-get-the-pressed-keys-in-swift-and-spritekit-at-every-update)

Answer (score 0):

Well using google you can search for lists or images of keyboards with the listed keycodes, however I suggest using problem solving for when something like that isn't available. When the keyPress event is called, print the keycode that was pressed. This way, you can press the space bar and it will tell you what the keycode of it was without having to rely on outside sources.